# HtmlEncode List<int, string> In MVC

Tags: c#, ienumerable, html-encode

I have a c# class object that is List<int,string>  I need to make sure the list's string variable is HtmlEncoded before passing back to an MVC controller (where I will later need to decode) but I'm having difficulty because the company's custom libraries are written in such a way that I have a hard time manipulating the code.

In this particular scenario, the data field is embedded into a SQL statement that is converted to the List<int,string> object.  Before this List<int,string> is passed back, I need to use WebUtility.HtmlEncode on the string variable "GroupName":

```
 public List<DatasetModel> GetMembers(List<int> groupIds)
    {
        using (var work in unitOfWorkFactory())
        {
            return work.DataContext.Query.Read<DatasetModel>(
                $@SELECT {nameof(TableOne.GroupId)
                    , {(nameof(TableOne.Name))} as GroupName
                    FROM {this._tableProvider.GlobalTable<TableOne>()}
                    WHERE {nameof(TableOne.GroupId)} {groupIds.ToSqlInClause()}"
            ).ToList();
            )
        }
    }
```

I've tried creating extension methods and something like the following but get type conversion errors, etc, that lead me to write rudimentary for loops and cast() and such that are not appropriate:

```
 List<DatasetModel> returnList = model.Select(x => new DatasetModel{x.GroupId, WebUtility.HtmlEncode(x.Name)}).ToList();
```

FOLLOW-UP:
Here is what I've had to do to achieve the goal.  I don't like it because I am using a foreach loop in the called method.  I haven't been able to consistently understand / resolve errors involving 'initializer errors' and List vs generic lists:

```
public List<DatasetModel> GetMembers(List<int> groupIds)
    {
        using (var work in unitOfWorkFactory())
        {

            return EncodeList(work.DataContext.Query.Read<DatasetModel>(
                $@SELECT {nameof(TableOne.GroupId)
                    , {(nameof(TableOne.Name))} as GroupName
                    FROM {this._tableProvider.GlobalTable<TableOne>()}
                    WHERE {nameof(TableOne.GroupId)} {groupIds.ToSqlInClause()}"
            ).ToList();
            )
        }
    }

private static List<DatasetModel> EncodeList(List<DatasetModel> list)
{
    var returnList = new List<DatasetModel>();
    foreach (var l in list)
    {
        var m = new DatasetModel(attributeId: l.attributeId, attributeName: WebUtility.HtmlEncode(l.attributeName));
        returnList.Add(m);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add what conversion errors you're getting?

Comment: Examples:

"Cannot initialize type 'DatasetModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'"

"Argument 1: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DatasetModel>' to 'DatasetModel'"

```
 var returnList = new List<DatasetModel>() {model.Select(x => new DatasetModel{ x.Id.ToString(), x.Name})}.ToList();  
```